# Default route interferes with defined path in attribute routing in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have a controller with an action method and I have configured attribute routing:

```
[RoutePrefix("foos")]
public class FooController : BaseController
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Here's routing configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
}
```

Everything works fine. When I navigate to `http://webPageAddress/foo/` my action is called and list is returned.

Now I want to make this route default. I've added new attribute so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/")]
[Route("")]
public ActionResult List()
{
    return View();
}
```

The result is default route (`http://webPageAddress/`) works, but the old one (`http://webPageAddress/foo/`) doesn't work anymore (http 404 code).

How can I mix it and have both configured properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the route for `http://webPageAddress/foo/` is registered *before* the route for `http://webPageAddress/`. With attribute routing, the only way to do this is to use the `Order` property to set the order.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/", Order = 2)]
[Route("", Order = 1)]
public ActionResult List()
{
    return View();
}
```

Reference: [Understanding Routing Precedence in ASP.NET MVC and Web API](http://rion.io/2015/11/13/understanding-routing-precedence-in-asp-net-mvc/)